# Heroku Multiple Apps

Tags: git, heroku

I have two Apps on Heroku and two directories to store them locally. I haven't initialised git in either directory yet but when I do and then run `git push heroku master` how do I specify which app it should be pushed to on Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone a repository, Git remembers which URL you cloned from. So if you clone from your Heroku repository, all you need to do is `git push` to send your code to the corresponding repository. Since each App's repository lives in a different URL, there should be no confusion.

Example:

```
git clone git@heroku.com:app1.git
cd app1
# work and commit
git push  # app1 is deployed (by being pushed to git@heroku.com:app1.git)

cd ..
git clone git@heroku.com:app2.git
cd app2
# work and commit
git push  # app2 is deployed (by being pushed to git@heroku.com:app2.git)
```

Or if you're starting from zero, but already have some files that you want to add to the repo:

```
cd app1
git init
git add .  # marks every file in the directory to be added to the repo
git commit -m "Initial import"
git remote add origin git@heroku.com:app1.git
git push origin master

# likewise for app2
```

Comment: @tommyd456 Yes. I edited my answer with an example, which I hope clarifies things a bit.

Comment: thanks for the extra info - however - I already have files on my local side so will these be overwritten if I clone the contents of an empty repo?

Comment: I've ended up using `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:project.git`

Comment: @tommyd456 Yes, that's it. I had just updated my answer with that.

Comment: sorry just seen your update too - got there in the end